# Слушать два порта с помощью gunicorn

Tags: python, gunicorn

В проекте, где я сейчас работаю, используется gunicorn, запускаемый из питоновского кода.

Для мониторинга возникла необходимость сделать отдельную ручку, в которой будет отдаваться статистика о работе сервиса.
Я хотел сделать эту ручку на отдельном порту, но что-то не получается.

Пробовал создать два gunicorn-приложения, но насколько я понял, при запуске gunicorn-приложения, оно входит в бесконечный цикл, в котором слушает порт, и дальше выполнение кода не идёт.
Пробовал создавать gunicorn-приложение в отдельном потоке, но оно тогда ругается, что запущено не в главном потоке.

Есть вообще какой-нибудь способ слушать два разных порта из одного питон-кода с помощью gunicorn? Запускать это двумя разными питон-приложениями не хочется, т.к. основная часть сервиса (которая работает на первом порту) должна активно отгружать статистику, которую я хочу отдавать на другом порту. А делать это двумя разными питон-приложениями и налаживать между ними обмен данными как-то чересчур.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ели запуск из питона имеется ввиду такой, то так:

```
import multiprocessing

import gunicorn.app.base


def number_of_workers():
    return (multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2) + 1


def handler_app(environ, start_response):
    response_body = b'Works fine'
    status = '200 OK'

    response_headers = [
        ('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
    ]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [response_body]

class StandaloneApplication(gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication):

    def __init__(self, app, options=None):
        self.options = options or {}
        self.application = app
        super().__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = {key: value for key, value in self.options.items()
                  if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None}
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = {
        'bind': '%s:%s' % ('127.0.0.1', '8080'),
        'workers': number_of_workers(),
    }
    
    options2 = {
        'bind': '%s:%s' % ('127.0.0.1', '8081'),
        'workers': number_of_workers(),
    }
    
    app = StandaloneApplication(handler_app, options)
    app2 = StandaloneApplication(handler_app, options2)
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=app2.run)
    p2.start()
    app.run()
    p2.terminate()
    p2.join()
```

Правда не жди clean shutdown на втором процессе...

Вот вариант получше, тут все необходимое для старта делается в основном потоке, а обработка сигналов перенесенна в фон. Тут момент что сигналы получит случайная апп, а не обе и не главная.

```
import multiprocessing
import threading


from gunicorn.errors import HaltServer, AppImportError
import gunicorn.app.base
from gunicorn.arbiter import Arbiter

def number_of_workers():
    return (multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2) + 1


def handler_app(environ, start_response):
    response_body = b'Works fine'
    status = '200 OK'

    response_headers = [
        ('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
    ]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [response_body]

class StandaloneApplication(gunicorn.app.base.BaseApplication):

    def __init__(self, app, options=None):
        self.options = options or {}
        self.application = app
        super().__init__()

    def load_config(self):
        config = {key: value for key, value in self.options.items()
                  if key in self.cfg.settings and value is not None}
        for key, value in config.items():
            self.cfg.set(key.lower(), value)

    def load(self):
        return self.application


def run(self):
        "Main master loop."

        try:
            self.manage_workers()

            while True:
                self.maybe_promote_master()

                sig = self.SIG_QUEUE.pop(0) if self.SIG_QUEUE else None
                if sig is None:
                    self.sleep()
                    self.murder_workers()
                    self.manage_workers()
                    continue

                if sig not in self.SIG_NAMES:
                    self.log.info("Ignoring unknown signal: %s", sig)
                    continue

                signame = self.SIG_NAMES.get(sig)
                handler = getattr(self, "handle_%s" % signame, None)
                if not handler:
                    self.log.error("Unhandled signal: %s", signame)
                    continue
                self.log.info("Handling signal: %s", signame)
                handler()
                self.wakeup()
        except (StopIteration, KeyboardInterrupt):
            self.halt()
        except HaltServer as inst:
            self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except Exception:
            self.log.info("Unhandled exception in main loop",
                          exc_info=True)
            self.stop(False)
            if self.pidfile is not None:
                self.pidfile.unlink()
            sys.exit(-1)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = {
        'bind': '%s:%s' % ('127.0.0.1', '8080'),
        'workers': number_of_workers(),
    }
    
    options2 = {
        'bind': '%s:%s' % ('127.0.0.1', '8081'),
        'workers': number_of_workers(),
    }
    
    app = StandaloneApplication(handler_app, options)
    app2 = StandaloneApplication(handler_app, options2)

    ar1 = Arbiter(app)
    ar1.start()
    
    ar2 = Arbiter(app2)
    ar2.start()


    t1 = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(ar1,))
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=run, args=(ar2,))
    
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    
    t1.join()
    t2.join()
```

Со статистикой всеже останется одна беда) воркеры работают в любом случае в отдельных процессах - для сбора статистики понадобится ещё один процесс с мультипроцессовой очередью для сбора и что-нибудь вроде менеджера для отдачи.